# SQL to select row where table field partially matches form textbox string

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a table named (`PostOff`) which has a field called `PAddress`
and a form textbox named `CAddress`.

I'm trying to write code to select a row where the `PAddress` partially matches the form textbox `CAddress`. To be more specific, select the row if `CAddress` contains the value of `PAddress` table field.

The code I use only works if `PAddress` perfectly matches `CAddress`:

```
("SELECT * FROM PostOff WHERE [PostOff.PAddress] Like  '" & Me.CAddress & "'")
```

I guess I need something like:

```
("SELECT * FROM PostOff WHERE "*[PostOff.PAddress]*" Like  '" & Me.CAddress & "'")
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Try: `"SELECT * FROM PostOff WHERE [PostOff.PAddress] Like  '*" & Me.CAddress& "*'"`

Comment: thanks but it didnt work gives me an error expected list sperator or ) and highlights the end of code "*'"

Comment: Please, see updated answer.

Comment: @MaciejLos thanks for your help but thats not what I exactly want to do let me use an example to explain it `me.CAddress` is `123 St, Town, City, US` and the field `PAddress` has only `town` so I want it to select the row from the table where `CAddress` contains a town which is stored in the table field `PAddress` hope this explains what I'm trying to achieve and thanks in advance :)

Comment: If `PAddress` contains only `town` and you want to find any of word entered into `Me.CAddress` textbox, you have to split words into list of word and compare it with `PAddress` field. There's no easy way to split words in MS Access sql statement, but it is quite easy with vba. But, you have to provide more details about data stored in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[MS Access solution]**

Accordingly to your comment...

If you want to find only `town` word in `PAdress` field, you'd use [IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208859%28v=office.12%29.aspx) operator.

```
sQry = "SELECT * FROM PostOff WHERE [PostOff.PAddress] IN (" & GetListOfWords(Me.CAddress) & ")"
```

A `GetListOfWords` function may look like:

```
Function GetListOfWords(ByVal sInputString As String) As String

Dim words() As String
Dim sResult  As String
Dim i As Integer

words = Split(Replace(sInputString, ",", ""), " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(words)
    sResult = sResult & "'" & words(i) & "',"
Next

GetListOfWords = Left(sResult, Len(sResult) - 1)

End Function
```

Above function returns: `'123','St','Town','City','US'`

Comment: thank you this code works without errors but it still didn't do the right job I want it to select the row if Me.CAddress contains [PostOff.PAddress]

Comment: % is for MySQL. For Access SQL use *.

Comment: @MaciejLos thank you so much for all your help I guess your function works but for me when I try it, it returns null so I'm gonna keep trying to figure it out forgive me I'm new to Access and VBA so I keep trying to get everything to work but thank you so much for your time and your help

Comment: You're very welcome. I tested id with string: `123 St, Town, City, US` passed into above finction. It works as charm.

Comment: @MaciejLos Thank you so much yes I found out your code works like a charm I finally figured out why it wasn't working for me I was testing it with two words town so it wasn't recognizing it and returns null but when I used a one word town I figured out it was working from the beginning but I still have no clue how to make it recognize two words town like `Oliver Springs` and select it from the table

Comment: Well, can you explain waht you mean? Do you want to find exact match?

Comment: @MaciejLos I'm so sorry I know I took alot of your time thank you so much for your help so far I really appreciate it lets me give you an example lets say thats the data stored in the table field `PAddress` is `Afton , Alamo , Allred , Oak Ridge .....` your code works like a charm with every single word town like `Alamo` but when it comes to two words town like `Oak Ridge` it selects nothing so if I entered  `123 St, Allred , City, US` it does the job and select it but if I entered `123 St, Oak Ridge, City, US` it doesnt do anything hope this makes it clear

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to use `%` to match anything in front or back of the string

```
("SELECT * FROM PostOff WHERE [PostOff.PAddress] Like  '%" & Me.CAddress & "%'")
```

Comment: that is not what I'm trying to do let me try it to explain more the string I type in `Me.CAddress` contains the full address Like house number , street and the town but the table field `PAddress` only contains the town I want it to select from the table where the field `PAddress` is a part of the string in `Me.CAddress` hope this explains what I'm trying to do and thanks for your help

Comment: So you want to match a part of `CAddress` string. For example :  `123 St, Town, City, US`. You need to extract `town` from `CAddress` string and then put it into the `SQL` query?

Comment: no thats not what I'm trying to do lets me use your example `CAddress` is `123 St, Town, City, US` but the field `PAddress` has only `town` so I want it to select the row from the table where `CAddress` contains a town which is stored in the table field.